# Why i can't send POST login to Spritg auth server?

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have Auth server with OAuth support with @EnableResourceServer.
[App configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnU0F.png)

[Security configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVzr8.png)

[Authorization server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TutjF.png)

I can GET to /login and fill form.
When i sent POST to /login, i have 401
[Error after POST /login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKfJu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might get help from my leaning experiment. I was also facing the same issue and adding `HttpMethod.POST` in antMatchers helped me and you should use `.authorizeRequests()` at the beginnings

```
 http
             .csrf().disable()
             .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login","/home","/failure").permitAll()
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN") 
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT,"/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
             .anyRequest().authenticated()
             .and()
             .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
             .and()
             .formLogin()
             .loginPage("/login")
             .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
             .usernameParameter("email")
             .passwordParameter("password")
             .defaultSuccessUrl("/home",true)
             .failureUrl("/failure")
             .and()
             .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").permitAll();
```